# Complex Object in Dojo Grid

Tags: json, dojo, dojox.grid

I want to know if its possible to populate the following object into a dojo grid

First off, the main object is a array of objects with 3 fields, 2 ints and ANOTHER ARRAY of objects with 5 fields. My question is, can I set-up a layout for the dojo grid to populate a grid with "subrows"

Here is a sample JSON

```
[{"ClaimID":1,"ClaimNumber":"4304021","LossDetails":[{"LossCause":"COLLISION                     ","LossDate":"\/Date(1136786400000-0600)\/",
    "LossExpense":95.00,"LossPaid":6415.21,"LossReserve":0.00},{"LossCause":"BODILY INJURY                 ","LossDate":"\/Date(1136786400000-0600)\/",
    "LossExpense":0.00,"LossPaid":250.00,"LossReserve":0.00},{"LossCause":"MEDICAL PAYMENTS              ","LossDate":"\/Date(1136786400000-0600)\/",
    "LossExpense":0.00,"LossPaid":0.00,"LossReserve":0.00},{"LossCause":"PROPERTY DAMAGE               ","LossDate":"\/Date(1136786400000-0600)\/",
    "LossExpense":0.00,"LossPaid":1893.99,"LossReserve":0.00}]}]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to familiarize yourself with the formatting tools, that way people will easier read your examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dojox.grid.TreeGrid`, the layout looks like:

```
new dojox.grid.TreeGrid({
    structure: [ 
        { cells: [
            [ 
                { field: "ClaimID", name: "ID" }, 
                { field: "ClaimNumber", name: "Number"},
                { field: "LossDetails", 
                    children: [
                        { field: "LossExpense", name: "LossExpense"}, 
                        { field: "LossCause", name: "LossCause" }, 
                        { field: "LossPaid", name: "LossPaid" }, 
                        { field: "LossReserve", name: "LossReserve" }, 
                        { field: "LossDate", name: "LossDate" } 
                    ]
                 }
             ]] 
         }                  
    ],
    store: jsonStore,
    queryOptions: {deep: true}
 }, dojo.byId("grid"));
```

Comment: Fabulous Answer...But Plz Can You please edit and add complete code including store and treeGrid   dojo variable...

Answer (score 2):

Or if you just want a single cell containing some child objects data, you can attach a formatter to a cell:

```
{ name: "Child data", field: "field_object", formatter: present_child_info}
...
function present_child_info(value) {
var s = "";
for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
s += value[i].attribute;
}
return s;
}
```